# Обновление блока по id без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пример функции, которая по клику на элементе обновляет блок с нужным id, не перезагружая всю страничку.

Comment: Уж больно пространно звучит идея. Что вы на самом деле хотите сделать?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под обновить элемент? Какие элементы хотите обновлять?

Comment: Да все просто есть корзина магазина. 
В ней список товаров, их кол-во и общая стоимость. На страничку они передаются в виде php переменной $_SESSION. 
По бокам от количества кнопки добавить убрать (-n+), собственно говоря при нажатие оно передает данные в cart.php который считает новую итоговую цену, ну и нужно обновить ее визуально на страничке без перезагрузки.

Comment: В сущности не важно что за элемент в моем случае это button и блок div

Comment: Для этого есть функция `Ajax`,  если я вас правильно  понял.

Comment: Да без Ajax тут не обойтись, но как я сказал у меня очень низкий уровень js, буду рад если кто ни будь покажет пример подобной функции...

Comment: @Alex [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @Grundy [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - тогда уж могли хотя бы так.

Comment: @Alex, ну если вы сами нашли ответ, можете опубликовать его и отметить его как принятый :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>` который хотим заменить

```
<div id="ajaxtest">
</div>

$('#ajaxtest').load(url,  function () { GenerateData(); });
```

такое можно использовать на перерисовки какого-либо блока. к примеру заменить на частичное представление.

`url` путь к частичному представлению

`function () { GenerateData(); }` rebing script

---

можно такой небольшой запрос вернуть какое-то значение или еще что то

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: url, 
    data: param,
    contentType:
    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (rusult) {
     },
    error: function (unused1, unused2, error)
    { alert(error); } 
});
```

Comment: спасибо за рабочий вариант с разъяснениями)

Comment: Я помечу ваше решение как верное не смотря на то что сам решил подобное. 
Если кто то наткнется на вопрос, то ниже есть еще рабочий пример решения.

Answer (score 1):

Простенький пример как работает Ajax.

Js:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   var id = "111"; // что отправляем
$.ajax({
   url: "cart.php",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "html",
   cache: false,
   data: {id: id},

  success: function(res){
     $('.blok_res')html(res);
  }
});
});
```

cart.php:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo "Что мы отправили "."<b>".$id."</b>";
```

Comment: благодарю за пример) но нужно именно перезагрузить блок было, но некоторым думаю будет полезно. Подобный код используется для счетчика товаров в корзинке у меня.

Answer (score 0):

Написал может пригодится кому.

```
 $("button[data-add_to_cart]").on('click',function(){
    $.post("cart.php", { order: $(this).data("unique-id")})
            .done(function(data) {
                $("#cart").load("page-cart #cart");
            });
 });
```

Код передает переменную в cart.php он проводит необходимые манипуляции пишет в переменную, далее обновляем нужный блок. Собственно решение задачи заключается в этой строчке

```
$("#cart").load("page-cart #cart");
```